# save data from dropdown list in create or edit action

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc-4

This is my Model.

```
public class Territory
    {
        [Display(Name = "ID", ResourceType = typeof(Resources.Resource))]
        public long ID { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Name", ResourceType = typeof(Resources.Resource))]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Code", ResourceType = typeof(Resources.Resource))]
        public string Code { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "ProviderKey", ResourceType = typeof(Resources.Resource))]
        public string ProviderKey { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Provider", ResourceType = typeof(Resources.Resource))]
        public string Provider { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Countries", ResourceType = typeof(Resources.Resource))]
        public virtual IList<Country> Countries { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Rights", ResourceType = typeof(Resources.Resource))]
        public IList<RightApplication> Rights { get; set; }
    }
```

This is my Controller Edit action.

```
 public ActionResult Edit(long id) {
            var territory = new db.Territories.FindAsync(id);
            if(territory == null) return HttpNotFound();
            ViewBag.Countries = new SelectList(db.Countries.AsEnumerable(), "ID", "Name");
            return View("Edit", territory);

        }
```

And this is my Index view.

```
@foreach (var item in Model.Items)
{
    <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-1">
        <h4 class="pull-right" style="margin:4px;"><a href="@Url.Action("Edit", "Territory", new {id=item.ID })"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i></a>-<a href="@Url.Action("Details", new { id = item.ID, isDelete = true })"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i></a></h4>
        <div class="panel panel-success territory panel-scroll">
            <div class="panel-heading">@item.Name</div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                <ul class="list-group">
                    @foreach (var country in item.Countries)
                    {
                        <li class="list-group-item">@country.Name</li>
                    }
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

This is my Create View.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm(htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form single-col" }))
    {
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ID)
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name)
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name)
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Code)
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Code)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Code)
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ProviderKey)
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ProviderKey)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ProviderKey)
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Provider)
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Provider)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Provider)
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Countries)
           @Html.DropDownList("Countries")

        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="controls">
                <div class="btn-group">
                    @if (Model.ID == 0)
                    {
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Create</button>
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i> Update</button>
                    }
                    <a class="btn btn-info" href="@Url.Action("Index")"><i class="fa fa-arrow-left"></i> Back to List</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    }
```

I'm trying  Country select from DropdownList to show in Index view.I have get Territory Name in index view,but i'm not able to add Country Name in Territory.

Comment: You have any Solution Please Provide me.

Comment: I see an un ordered list here but I don't see a drop down.  What data are you wanting sent back to the controller?

Comment: I have sent my Create View.

Comment: Firstly Check into database whether you have multiple Contries for the Territory or not.

Answer (score 0):

there are 2 ways to save the data from the drop down.  The first is a little more work and isn't as reliable.  Look at the rendered drop down and if there isn't a name on it, add one

```
@Html.DropDownList("Countries", Model.CountriesList, new { name = "Country" })
```

with that on your controller you can get the selected value by

```
Request.Form["Country"].ToString();
```

the way I would recommend is to change your drop down to a for helper

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.Country, Model.CountriesList)
```

this will tie the selected value to your model (Country in this case) which you can then pull out in your post method